# Date Entity Class files and multiple schemas

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, schema

Scenario:
Database with multiple schemas, e.g. [dbo],[s1],[s2].

A schema may contain a table that has the same name as a table in another schema but they may not necessarily have the same definition, such that [dbo].[table1] may or may not be the same as [s1].[table1].

I've created an app that generates the class files. For instance, here is the generated class file for [dbo].[StudentRemote] with some modifications to hide some encryption info:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace FlexIT.Model
{
    namespace dbo
    {
        public class StudentRemote
        {
            private Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();

            public StudentRemote()
            {
                RecordTimeStamp = null;
                WeeklyMeetingTime = null;
                WeeklyMeetingDay = null;
                CWUCatalogNumber = null;
                Salt = null;
                RawApplicationText = null;
                Status = null;
                BreakupDate = null;
                MentorAssignedDate = null;
                MentorID = null;
                EmploymentHoursPerWeek = null;
                TransferDegreeDate = null;
                TransferDegreeInstitution = null;
                TransferDegree = null;
                CompleteBy = null;
                StartDate = null;
                AcceptDate = null;
                ApplicationDate = null;
                RecordCreateDate = null;
                FirstContactLogID = null;
                Resume = null;
                CoverLetter = null;
                CWUID = null;
                Zip = null;
                State = null;
                City = null;
                Address2 = null;
                Address1 = null;
                PhoneNumber = null;
                EmailAddressCWU = null;
                EmailAddressPersonal = null;
                Position = null;
                Employer = null;
                Gender = null;
                Birthdate = null;
                LastName = null;
                MI = null;
                FirstName = null;
            }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "ID", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            [Key]
            public Guid ID
            {
                get { return _id; }
                set { _id = value; }
            }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "FirstName", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false,Salt="one")]
            public String FirstName { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "MI", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false,Salt="two")]
            public String MI { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "LastName", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false,Salt="three")]
            public String LastName { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Birthdate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Gender", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Gender { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Employer", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Employer { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Position", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Position { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "EmailAddressPersonal", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String EmailAddressPersonal { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "EmailAddressCWU", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String EmailAddressCWU { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "PhoneNumber", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Address1", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Address1 { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Address2", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Address2 { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "City", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String City { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "State", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String State { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Zip", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Zip { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "CWUID", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String CWUID { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "CoverLetter", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String CoverLetter { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Resume", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Resume { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "FirstContactLogID", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public Int32? FirstContactLogID { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "RecordCreateDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? RecordCreateDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "ApplicationDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? ApplicationDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "AcceptDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? AcceptDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "StartDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "CompleteBy", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? CompleteBy { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "TransferDegree", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String TransferDegree { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "TransferDegreeInstitution", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String TransferDegreeInstitution { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "TransferDegreeDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? TransferDegreeDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "EmploymentHoursPerWeek", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public Int32? EmploymentHoursPerWeek { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "MentorID", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public Guid? MentorID { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "MentorAssignedDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? MentorAssignedDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "BreakupDate", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? BreakupDate { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Status", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public Int32? Status { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "RawApplicationText", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String RawApplicationText { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "Salt", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String Salt { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "CWUCatalogNumber", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String CWUCatalogNumber { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "WeeklyMeetingDay", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public String WeeklyMeetingDay { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "WeeklyMeetingTime", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public DateTime? WeeklyMeetingTime { get; set; }

            [Mapping(ColumnName = "RecordTimeStamp", IsUpdateable = true, IsIdentity = false)]
            public Byte[] RecordTimeStamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class StudentRemoteController : Controller<StudentRemote>
        {
            // Create generic controller at runttime
            public StudentRemoteController() : base("StudentRemote", "ID", "table", "dbo")
            {
            }
            // Create custom methods here
            // Use "public new" to completely override a method in the generic controller
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a primary namespace -- FlexIT.Model -- and a "sub namespace" which is the schema for the table entity.

So...

In my applications that call this entity model, I do something like the following. (This code queries [dbo].[StudentRemote] and decrypts the first name.)

You can see in my using statements what I'm trying to do and how I'm doing it.

My question -- is there a better way to deal with multiple schemas in the same entity model?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using fm=FlexIT.Model;
using fmdbo=FlexIT.Model.dbo;
using fmtemp=FlexIT.Model.temp;
using clsCrypto;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace FlexIT
{
    class Program
    {
        static public string FlexITKey = "FakeKeyForSecurityPurposes";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = new fm.dbo.StudentRemoteController();
            // or...
            // var src = fmdbo.StudentRemoteController();
            // or, if we were querying [temp].[StudentRemote]...
            // var src = fm.temp.StudentRemoteController();
            // or...
            // var src = fmtemp.StudentRemoteController();
            //
            src.Gets(pKeyname: "ID", pKeyval:new Guid(), pWhere:"or id is not null");

            foreach (var sr in src.InsertRec)
            {
                foreach (var prop in typeof(fm.dbo.StudentRemote).GetProperties())
                {
                    AttributeCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(fmdbo.StudentRemote))[prop.Name].Attributes;
                    fm.MappingAttribute myMappings = (fm.MappingAttribute)attributes[typeof(fm.MappingAttribute)];
                    if (myMappings.Salt != null)
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(sr, DecryptIt(prop.GetValue(sr, null).ToString(), myMappings.Salt, sr.Salt));
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sr.FirstName);
            }          
        }

        public static string DecryptIt(string encryptedString, string additionalSalt = "", string recordSalt = "")
        {
            //s=encrypted string
            //e=additional salt
            //h=record salt if needed. This is usually the student's salt value


            CryptoFilterBox mycrypto = new CryptoFilterBox();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedString) || encryptedString.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                return encryptedString;
            }
            mycrypto.set_InBuffer(encryptedString.Replace("''", "'"));
            mycrypto.set_Password(FlexITKey + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recordSalt) ? "" : recordSalt) + additionalSalt);
            mycrypto.Decrypt();
            return mycrypto.OutBuffer;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So you are creating a different context for each schema (fm, fmdbo, fmtemo) ?

Comment: That's one of my questions

1. Is the secondary namespace necessary
2. If it is, proper way to address it?
    fm.dbo.StudentController()?
    fmdbo.StudentController()?

Does the second way add overhead because of "using fmdbo=FlexIT.Model.dbo"?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: OK, I thought you has a separate context per.